# Как правильно выделять элементы в ListView?

Tags: android-sdk, android, listview

В моём приложении используется PagerAdapter( примерно тоже самое что и ViewFlipper, только элементы прокручиваются плавно и с автодоводкой ).

Данный PagerAdapter отображает несколько ListView.
Скажите пожалуйста как правильно выделять те элементы ListView, по которым нажал пользователь.
Я делаю это след образом:

```
public class MainActivity implements OnItemClickListener
{

...
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) 
    {
         arg1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.selectionColor);
    }
}
```

т.е. я создаю некий экземпляр ListView, например allListView, и вешаю на него обработчик, выглядит это примерно так:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    ...
    this.allListView = (ListView)this.allPage.findViewById(R.id.torrentsListView);
    this.allList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    this.allListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    this.allListAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, allList,
            R.layout.torrent_status_row,
            new String[] { HIDDEN_ID, TORRENT_CONTENT_NAME }, 
            new int[] { R.id.hiddenIDTextView, R.id.nameTorrentTextView });
    this.allListView.setAdapter(allListAdapter);
```

Таким образом когда пользователь нажимает на элемент в ListView у этого элемента должен меняться фон, однако, на самом деле, если в списке боьше одного элемента, то при нажатии на первый выделится последний, при нажатии на второй выделится предпоследний и т.д.

Пожалуйста, подскажите как правильно выделять элементы в таком случае и избежать этой проблемы.

Спасибо.

P.S. этот деффект не воспроизводится на Android 3.0 и выше

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас нигде не указан MULTI_CHOISE...не помню как

Если есть то надо заменить на NONE. Но обработку надо самому писать

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, что именно Вы имеете ввиду под обрабткой?

Comment: Ну по идее у вас тут она вручную и сделана)

http://ivanovsuper.blogspot.com/2010/10/android.html#more

Посмотрите может вам поможет (по-моему подобная проблема)
Кстати блог участника @Yura Ivanov, если Вам что-то отсюда поможет запилите ему плюсик где-нибудь)

Comment: Спасибо, Вы очень помогли

Answer (score 2):

во первых если у вас списки то нужно использовать

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

}
```

вместо обычного onItemClick
во вторых вы могли чтонибудь с имплементацией намутить не так и из-за этого косяки. Рекомендую использовать [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html)

Comment: По-моему в данной реализации как раз OnItemClick(...) 
Да и разве есть принципиальная разница?

Comment: Что бы использовать onListItemClick необходимо что бы мой класс наследовал ListActivity. А мне его не получается унаследовать, так как это требует что бы в моей Activitiy был ListView, а там его нет, потому что он внутри PagerAdapter'а. Если унаследоваться от него то при запуске мне выкидывают исключение: 
**java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'**

Comment: ясное дело. потому что у каждого списка должен быть свой обработчик, т.е. listview.setOnListItemClick (или как то так). Второй вариант - использовать какойто свой адаптер вместо SimpleAdapter - тогда можно будет внутри getView добавить обработчик нажатия

Comment: @alvin совсем не поэтому по-моему. А потому что ListActivity требует у списка id из пакета android равный тому что как раз и написано. На обычный листвью в обычном Activity можно повешать обработчик OnItemClickListener(...) без последствий